# Running Jar on Snow Leopard with classpath

Tags: java, osx-snow-leopard, classpath

I'm running snow leopard and I just wrote a Java class on eclipse. The eclipse project references a user library which itself points to a bunch of jar files I've got somewhere in the system. When I run the app through eclipse, everything goes smoothly. 
Then I export the class as a jar file and try to run it form the terminal by typing:

```
java - jar myApp.jar
```

It throws a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception, meaning that it can't find the libraries I try to reference. 
Knowing that my user library jar files are in /Users/myname/tempJars, I also tried to either mention the classpath using the -cp option 
`(java -cp /Users/myname/tempJars -jar myApp.jar)` or to directly reference it in the manifest file. Both attempts failed and the error is the same.
These libraries are Java 1.5 libraries, so I thought I should try and reference another java version by mean of the JAVA_HOME environment variable. I built the following script:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/myname/tempJars

java -jar myApp.jar
```

Again, no good. I googled how to execute jars in snow leopard, found the 32/64 bit big deal in some places and even tried executing with the -d32 option, but still to no avail.
Since the same code executes just fine in eclipse, I'm pretty convinced it's just a matter of setting up the JVM so that it includes the user libraries correctly.

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to list the JARs themselves out on the classpath, not just the directory containing them.  (Listing the directory is for when you have unarchived .class files in the package hierarchy lying around)

You will probably need to do `-cp /Users/myname/tempJars/libA.jar:/.../libB.jar`

I believe some (but potentially not all) JVMs support wildcards so `-cp /Users/myname/tempJars/*` or some variant thereof may work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, adding the jars individually worked well.

Comment: It should probably be `-cp '/Users/myname/tempJars/*'` so that the shell doesn't prematurely expand the wildcard (assuming the JVM wildcard syntax works at all).